# How to set the flash as default in media plugin in Xamarin?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

for media plugin, there have default camera which is

```
DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Front
```

If i want make the flash light was always on, so any default function can be set like the default camera?

I use the Lamp.Plugin combine with media plugin, so the code like below:

```
 CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported && !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Message", "Photo Capture and Pick Not supported", "ok");
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            CrossLamp.Current.TurnOn();

            var file = CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                //DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Front,
                CompressionQuality = 92,
                SaveToAlbum = true,
                Directory = "Image",
                Name = DateTime.Now + "_test.jpg"
            });
```

But above code only able to activate lamp but not the camera

Answer (score 1):

This **isn't available** in the Media Plugin as of now. However there is an open feature request that can be found [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/380).

If you don't want to wait you can use the [Lamp Plugin](https://github.com/kphillpotts/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Lamp).

Be aware that you do need to add the following permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

After that you can use the plugin like this `CrossLamp.Current.TurnOn();` and `CrossLamp.Current.TurnOff();`

Comment: If you dig in a little deeper you can find a fork someone is working on: https://github.com/Philyorkshire/MediaPlugin/tree/feature/camera-flash-setting

Comment: I have used the Lamp plugin, but this 2 different plugin look like not able work at the same time

Comment: @ShiJieTio They should be able to, have you initialised both plugins correctly? Which exception are you getting?

Comment: When the camera button was click the lamp will be activate but the camera will just shut down

Comment: Yes I added already, but only can work for flash but not the camera

Comment: Can you add some logging? @ShiJieTio

Comment: hi, may i know what does the logging mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166067/discussion-between-shi-jie-tio-and-trevi-awater).